# PHP preg_match cannot find a match

Tags: php, regex

The following code should be able to find a match but it does not. Online Regular Expression Test sites are able do find a match. Try for instance on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/php/index.html. What is wrong with my code?

```
<?php
    if (preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,200}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}", "abc.jpg")) {
        echo "A match was found.";
    } else {
        echo "A match was not found.";
    }
?>
```

Result:

```
A match was not found
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: `$re = "/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,200}\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}/"; 
$str = "abc.jpg"; 
 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you